# sql sum different column value descending

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this query:

```
 Available Total Usage

7000.0     7021.9
7000.0    -15000.00
7000.0    -7700.85
```

I want to create new column to sum both column in descending order.The result I wish is

```
Available         Total Usage         Total
7000.0    7021.9 -700.85+(-15000.00) = -15700.85
7000.0    -15000.00 7000+(-7700.85)  = -700.85
7000.0    -7700.85  7000
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
with cte as(select Available, [Total Usage], Available+[Total Usage] as Total from <table>)
select * from CTE order y Total
```

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention, the query still have one column named date(month and year), i need to sum in descending order based on date. Isit i just need to change above order y Total based on date?

Comment: and i realise, if use the answer u provide, i cant get total 7000 for my last record
Total
-700.85+(-15000.00) = -15700.85
7000+(-7700.85) = -700.85
7000

Comment: @ElynnChia: I am not getting how do you get 7000. by adding 7000+(-7700.85) . ?

Comment: the 7000 carry from Available column last value to Total column.